# Why cant i access my webserver outside my LAN

Tags: apache, webserver, portforwarding, raspberry-pi4

I have a webdomain named "personabot.ml" which i am able to access when im on any device connected to my local internet but cannot access it from outside i just get `personabot.ml took too long to respond`.
I have portforwarded the local ip to my external ip and then the domain is returning to my external ip.
The web server is running on apache on by raspberry pi 4.

Comment: Look at your `httpd.conf` or maybe your `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: Have yo portforwarded your router, for port 80 ontop the Pi machine?

Comment: Yes i have i can access the webpage which is being portforwarded to my local ip which means the portforward is working properly as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly Wait i read that wrong what exactly do you mean by portforwarding my "router" isnt portwarding the rpi enough and if not how can i do that.

Comment: https://portforward.com/

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I already did that

Comment: I checked, `personabot.ml` resolves to 182.68.191.131, which is - hopefully - your public IP address.  In your router you have to port forward port 80 external, to port 80 on the pi.  Maybe that is what you did, but your sentence seems to indicate you did the reverse.  I am able to connect to port 80 of your domain, but a `GET /` get disconnected, indicating a router / firewall issue.  Note that your ISP might be blocking server traffic as well.  FYI being able to access the page internally proves your pi responds, not that the port forwarding is ok.

Comment: @Nic3500 it was indeed a router issue not allowing wan to access http on the router luckily got a new router and fixed it.
Edit: The portforward was working as i could access the domain(and using the external ip as well) internally not just using the local ip.